# How to download XHR split video in many files (youtube-dl doesn't recognize the video platform/URL)

Tags: video, download, xmlhttprequest

I already read a lot of posts and articles explaining about the XHR files. By what I understood, the video platform splits the video file into many small files, which are downloaded in a buffer/cache as the play goes on. I tried a lot of ways and it seems there are some encryption or so which blocks many ways to get it. I even tried "youtube-dl" and it doesn't recognize.

Below is a picture of the "inspection":

[image: Google Inspection Screenshot]

This is the platform link: [Video Platform](https://www.hotmart.com/en)

PS.: I run Windows and MacOS. I have CURL, but don't have WGET.